# Make Square images in Volley.NetworkingImageView

Tags: android, android-volley

I have the following xml implementation, but i would like to make the images bigger and square. Sorry if my question is easy, please consider that I started a couple of weeks on Android development.

**Grid.xml**

```
 <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2"/>
```

**GridItem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#55000000"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Here is my adapter class code if needed:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
        }

        NetworkImageView imageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

        ImageRecord imageRecord = getItem(position);

        imageView.setImageUrl(imageRecord.getUrl(),mImageLoader);
        textView.setText(imageRecord.getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: try this tutorial...http://cypressnorth.com/mobile-application-development/setting-android-google-volley-imageloader-networkimageview/

Answer (score 0):

Start by setting a fixed size for your `NetworkImageView`:

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```